# Code not working for odd number at tens and hundreds's place

Tags: python, python-3.x, math

question is:

> Write a program, which will find all such numbers between m and n (both included) such that each digit of the number is an even number.
>
> Input Format:
>   The first line contains value m and n separated by a comma.
>
> Output Format:
>   The numbers obtained should be printed in a comma-separated sequence on a single line.
>
> Constraints:
>
> - `1000<=m<=9000`
> - `1000<=n<=9000`

However my code only works when no odd number is present at hundreds and thousands place. Where am I going wrong? Test cases and expected results:

**Test Case 1**

- input: 2000,2020
- output: 2000,2002,2004,2006,2008,2020

**Test Case 2**

- input: 2000,2050
- output: 2000,2002,2004,2006,2008,2020,2022,2024,2026,2028,2040,2042,2044,2046,2048

**Test Case 3**

- input: 1000,2000
- output: 2000

Test case 3 is failing in my case. Why is it so?

```
num=list(map(int,input().split(",")))
length=len(num)
list=[]
first=num[0]
last=num[length-1]
for i in range(first,last+1):
    count=0
    num1 = i
    k=i
    for j in range(4):
        last_digit=k%10
        k=i//10
        if(last_digit%2==0):
            count=count+1
    if(count==4):
        list.append(num1)
length2=len(list)
for i in range(length2):
    if(i<length2-1):
        print(list[i],end=',')
    else:
        print(list[i])
```

Comment: And I'd use `itertools.product()` and `24680` to generate values. You do need to use a loop to clear each power of 10 from `m` that didn't start at `0` first, increasing the number of digits you generate, until you've reached `n`.

Comment: The problem can be totally solved w/o any math, just by comparing characters: https://paste.openttdcoop.org/pxhdxo9yw

Comment: for m=2000 and n=2020 i get correct output
2000,2002,2004,2006,2008,2020 but for m=1000 and n=2000 i get wrong output 1000,1002,1004,1006,1008 when it shouldnt print anything for this case

Comment: Seems to me that you are making this needlessly complicated. An approach like @planetmaker suggests is possible, but more readable and understandable would be to set up a for-loop as you did and immediately `continue` if your number is not even or when `any` of its digits is not even. (Note the keyword `any`.) If the number survives these conditionals, you can add them to your final list.

Comment: @planetmaker: the set operations can be cleaned up a bit, but that's also a decent approach. Slower than generating the valid numbers from digits, but decent.

Comment: @planetmaker: there are [specific subset operators](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set) you can use instead of creating a new set object with an intersection operator, and testing if a set is empty is simply `not <set>`. See https://paste.openttdcoop.org/pp4mfiqxw

Comment: What if you debug the code? Put `print` commands for all of your variables and see what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error lies here:

```
k=i
for j in range(4):
    last_digit=k%10
    k=i//10
```

You are assigning `i // 10` to `k` each iteration, and `i` never changes, so you always only look at the last two digits, never anything else. If `i` starts at `1234`, then `k` starts at `1234`, `last_digit` becomes `4` and `k` becomes `123`. From there on out, you only look at `123` (`last_digit` will be `3` and `k = i // 10` so `123` again, each iteration).

You need to divide `k`:

```
k=i
for j in range(4):
    last_digit=k%10
    k=k//10
```

A simpler method would be to compare the *digits* (string values) to the set of even digits:

```
even = set('02468')

results = []
for i in range(first, last + 1):
    if set(str(i)) <= even:  # only even digits used
        results.append(i)
```

Comment: Ah, this is even a nicer solution with sets. Also thanks for the other pointers; I'm relatively new to python myself, too. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

For readability's sake, I'd write something like so:

```
nums = list(map(int, input().split(",")))
all_even = []

for num in range(nums[0], nums[1]+1):
  # Skips the num if it's not even
  if num % 2 != 0:
    continue

  # Skips the num if any of its digits is not even
  # Note that it'll skip on the first item that is not even
  # so it is rather efficient as it does not necessarily 
  # need to iterate over *all* digits
  if any(int(digit) % 2 != 0 for digit in str(num)):
    continue

  # Appends the num to the final list
  all_even.append(str(num))

print(','.join(all_even))
```

Comment: Actually, I do not think it is more *readable* - and not judging it; this was my first thought, too. It's the usual mathematicians or programmer's approach, used when sets are not an easy option as in python.

Comment: @planetmaker I've had many discussions about readability with other Python developers. And it seems that most developers all have a different idea of readability, which is OK of course. For me this is readable because every step in the selective thought process to include a number or not is written as a separate condition. I can read it as: *if the number itself is not even, skip it* and *if any of its digits is not even, skip the number* and finally *otherwise, include the number*. But to each their own, so if you don't think it's readable then that's okay of course.

Comment: I totally understand the approach - roughly your approach was my first take, too. And coming to mind first place it's reasonably easy to understand, thus readable. It's more a matter of from which perspective one looks at things, and thus indeed more or less a choice of personal - or project - preference. Mostly I'm saying, most programming languages make the set perspective I finally chose absolutely undesirable and unreadable. Python not so.